# Transfer "Injustice: Gods Among Us" saved game from iOS to Android

Tags: applications, data-transfer, ios

I have been playing *Injustice: Gods Among Us* on my iOS on the iPad and now I have an Android phone. I want to transfer the saved game to my Android: characters, challenges, cards, money, all of that.

I have downloaded the game already, I only need the data.

Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: It's not very common for locally saved games to work across platforms.  We can't help you with getting app data from iOS on this site though, even if this game's data is cross-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If the game is using a platform independent way of saving the game (eg. Facebook) then connecting the game to that account is enough and it should ask you to restore your save state like in Clash of clans or Boom beach.